# Appolonius' identity

Tags: inner-products

> Verify by direct calculation that for any elements in an inner product space, $$\|z-x\|^2+\|z-y\|^2=\frac 12\|x-y\|^2+2\|z-\frac12(x+y)\|^2$$

How can I derive this identity *without using the Parallelogram law*? I am trying to do direct calculation as the problem is asking. I think it's easier to start on the right side of the equation.

All I have so far, in terms of using definitions of inner products:
$$\|z-x\|^2+\|z-y\|^2=\langle z-x,z-x\rangle+\langle z-y,z-y \rangle$$
$$\frac 12\|x-y\|^2+2\|z-\frac12(x+y)\|^2=\frac12 \langle x-y,x-y \rangle+2 \langle z-\frac12(x+y),z-\frac 12(x+y)\rangle$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the vector space is over $\mathbb{C}$, we have $\|x+y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2\,\mathrm{Re}\langle x,y\rangle$. Of course, this holds in a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, but there, $\mathrm{Re}\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$.

$$
\begin{align}
\|z-x\|^2+\|z-y\|^2
&=\langle z-x,z-x\rangle+\langle z-y,z-y\rangle\\[8pt]
&=\|z\|^2+\|x\|^2-2\,\mathrm{Re}\langle z,x\rangle+\|z\|^2+\|y\|^2-2\,\mathrm{Re}\langle z,y\rangle\\[4pt]
&=\frac12\left(\|x-y\|^2+\|x+y\|^2\right)+2\|z\|^2-2\,\mathrm{Re}\langle z,x+y\rangle\\
&=\frac12\|x-y\|^2+\frac12\left(\|x+y\|^2-4\,\mathrm{Re}\langle z,x+y\rangle+4\|z\|^2\right)\\
&=\frac12\|x-y\|^2+\frac12\|x+y-2z\|^2\\
&=\frac12\|x-y\|^2+2\left\|\frac{x+y}2-z\right\|^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Will the relation $$\langle z-x,z-x \rangle = \|z\|^2+\|x\|^2-2\langle z, x \rangle$$ also work if the inner product space contains vectors with complex numbers? I remember that if the inner product space is complex, then $\langle x,y \rangle = \overline{\langle y,x \rangle}$, where the right hand side of that relation is the complex conjugate of $\langle y,x \rangle$. Otherwise, if the inner product space is for real numbers only, then $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle y,x \rangle$, which must explain how the second equality in your work holds true.

Comment: @legâteauaufromage: I have adjusted the answer to cover complex vector spaces, using $\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle=2\,\mathrm{Re}\langle x,y\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

you need the fact that for any $x,y$:
$$
\|x-y\|^2 = \langle x-y,x-y \rangle = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2 - 2\langle x,y \rangle
$$